# Program is returning the following TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am getting the above type error:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly.

line 34, in `<lambda>`

```
output[column] = output['Index_for_s'].apply(lambda x: s(x, column, file_two))
```

when trying to run the program below:

```
import pandas as pd

import os


def get_index(x, data):
    return list(data[data['COL1'] == x].index)


def suvrule(ind, col, data):
    data=pd.DataFrame(data)
    return  data.ix [ind,col].sum() 

file_one_path = input('Please enter file one: ')
file_two_path = input('Please enter file two: ')

if os.path.exists(file_one_path) and os.path.exists(file_two_path):
    file_one = pd.read_csv(file_one_path)
    file_two = pd.read_csv(file_two_path)
    try:
        assert (file_one.shape[0] == file_one.shape[0])
    except AssertionError:
        print ("Check Data.")
        exit()

    output = file_one.groupby('COL1', sort='False')['COL2'].agg('count').reset_index()
    output['Index_for_s'] = output['COL1'].apply(lambda x: get_index(x, file_one))
    cols_for_s = [col for col in file_two.columns if 'Header' not in col]
    for column in cols_for_s:
        output[column] = output['Index_for_s'].apply(lambda x: s(x, column, file_two))
    output = output.drop('Index_for_s', axis= 1)
    print ("\nWriting output to output.csv in current working directory.")
    output.to_csv("output.csv",  index='False')
else:
    print ('Incorrect file path')
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. There is no need for half of this code here. What is `s`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: s should be suvrule

Comment: @MiguelA You know you can edit your question, don't you? If it should be `suvrule`, change it.

Comment: It does not allow me to edit, since my post is mostly code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
change the line to this.
    [str(Index_for_s)]

Comment: I think where you wrote s(x, column, file_two) you were soppose to write suvrule(x,column,file_two) because i dont see s defined anywhere.

Comment: That was made when uploading the code, it is correctly written and defined in the program I am running.

Comment: Were trying to concat a str and an integer together. Python, by default, will not automatically convert that for you.   try output[""join(str(e) for e in index_for_x)] if this doesnt work then i nees to see a bit more of ur code

Comment: Have a read of this and see if you can relate: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/python-typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either, this is all the code I have written so far. I uploaded it because I can't see where it's having a problem. maybe the problem is in the survrule function, since it is called from that line of code

Comment: Maybe it should be `output[str(column)]`

Comment: If that dont work try wraping your lambda bracket with str(lambda...), i honestly have no clue now. Im sorry

Comment: When I try wraping my lambda bracket with str(lambda...), I get    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable ...thank you for trying!

Comment: Sorry i couldnt help. I hope u find your solution. I know how it feels. Its been nice talking.